# Missing data & single imputation

Tags: spss, missing-data

I have a complete ozone data set which consist a few missing values. I would like to use SPSS to do single imputation to impute my data.

Before I start impute my data, I would like to do randomly simulate missing data patterns with 5%, 10%, 15%, 25% and 40% of the data missing in order to evaluating the accuracy of imputation methods.

Can someone please teach me how to do the randomly missing data pattern by using SPSS?

Besides that can someone please tell me how to obtain the performance indicator such as: mean absolute error, coefficient of determination and root mean square error in order to check the best method for estimating missing values.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, my current SPSS supports no missing data analysis, so I can only give some general advice.

First: For your missing data pattern: Simply go to Data -> Select cases -> Random Sample and delete the desired amount of cases and then run the Imputation.

The values you mentioned should be provided by spss if you use their imputation module. There is a manual:
ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/20.0/de/client/Manuals/IBM_SPSS_Missing_Values.pdf

Comment: thanks for the help and link. then do you know how to get the performance indicator to test the goodness of fit?

Comment: No sorry - I have not used this module for 2 years and would have to see the actual output..

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question. Assume your study variable is `y` and you want to simulate missingness of the variable `y`. This is en example code to compute extra variable `y_miss` according to your missing data pattern.

```
do if uniform(1) < .05.
comp y_miss = $SYSMIS.
else.
comp y_miss = y.
end if.
```

Comment: Do you have formulas how to compute the indicators?